# failed: Invoked an instruction with data that is too large (12884932884 > 10240)'

Tags: anchor, solana-test-validator, local-cluster, localnet

```
failed: Invoked an instruction with data that is too large (12884932884 > 10240)'
```

i have this error when i try run test in my anchor program, but this only using local validator when i try using SolPg and devnet all work.

i try using amman at this moment
versions:
solana-cli: 1.16.9
anchor: 0.28.0
cargo: 1.65.0

Answer (score 1):

there is an issue in solana labs's github, check this link : https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960